# Is there a way to refresh the favicons of all tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, tabs, favicon

**Edit:** I realized I didn't clarify what I wanted. If I have a bunch of unloaded tabs without the favicons loaded, I want to load the favicons for all tabs without loading them.

I often restore tabs and browser sessions using the Tab Session Manager addon, with lazy loading and the discarded property enabled:

[image]

This loads tabs quickly with their favicons, but sometimes it fails to load certain tabs and loads new tab pages in their place instead which gets really frustrating. I could turn off the discarded property, but then it loads the page again and adds an entry to my browsing history which I don't want, it doesn't when the property is on. If I turn it off entirely then all the tabs would load, and too many at once would lag my computer.

Sometimes though, Firefox just doesn't load favicons and I want to load them manually. I'd like a way to load the favicon for all tabs without loading them.

Comment: Could it be that some favicons have a limited or rather short lifetime, while others don't? If so, Firefox may discard the expired icons (i.e. needing a reload to re-display), while others are still in the browser cache and thus can be displayed without reloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to load the favicon of a tab that's created in the "discarded" state, without loading the tab. Please see [Support "discarded" property for browser.tabs.create() · Issue #280 · sienori/Tab-Session-Manager](https://github.com/sienori/Tab-Session-Manager/issues/280), and vote for, but don't comment on, the Firefox bug on this issue: [1475240 - allow setting favicon when creating discarded tabs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1475240).

There is an addon called [Reload Discarded Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reload-discarded-tabs/) that addresses this issue, but it works by loading each tab and then discarding it again. It's extremely slow, and sometimes doesn't work, but at least it doesn't add entries to your history.

Comment: Hi Elhem, I am the author of the addon (https://github.com/irvinm/ReloadDiscardedTabs) you mentioned here and on the bugzilla issue. (PS. I am comment #2 [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1475240#c2] on that bugzilla issue) Let me know if there is anything I can do to improve the addon. You are right that it is slow, but when I let it go faster, Firefox did not appreciate loading many tabs at the same time and had problems with memory and\or discarding the tab properly. Obviously, the best solution is for them to allow loading of the favico when creating a discarded tab.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the addon. I understand the slowness isn't your fault. I do have a suggestion or two, so I'll post something in the Github repo.